# Rubymine/IntelliJ skipping rails server breakpoints during Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, minitest, rubymine

I'm debugging a minitest test case which makes a client GraphQL call into the Rails server. For some reason it doesn't stop at any breakpoints in my resolver. It stops at breakpoints throughout the test case and client side code. It's definitely running code in the resolver as I have modified the resolver adding puts statements and verified they show in the logs. My coworker seems to have no problems hitting breakpoints in the server.

Comment: Which RubyMine version are you using?

Comment: I'm using RubyMine version 2019.3.3 and IntelliJ 2019.3.3 build 193.6494.35

Comment: If possible please check RubyMine 2020.3.2 or 2020.3.3 Preview/2021.1 EAP. If the problem persists then it'd be great if you could share a project sample where it can be reproduced.